# Converting from GEOTIFF to JPEG2000

Tags: geotiff-tiff, fme-form, jpg

I need to convert raster from one format to another (geotiff-->jpeg2000). First I tried with very simple workspace, having input geotiff and direct to output jpeg2000, but I got error message:
JPEG2000 writer: This format cannot support palettes. Consider removing or resolving palettes that are attached to the raster

What should I do?

Answer (score 7):

How about using GDAL?  It is available via [FWTools](http://fwtools.maptools.org/) (easier install) on Windows, via apt-get on Ubuntu, and via a [binary](http://www.kyngchaos.com/software/frameworks) for OSX.

Once you have GDAL just go ahead and use:

```
gdal_translate -of JP2OpenJPEG <input> <output>
```

or

```
gdal_translate -of JPEG2000 <input> <output>
```

The above command uses the built in JP2 format conversion.  ECWJP2 or Kakadu might give you better results but they require a license.

Comment: Why "to do the same task" ECWJP2 or Kakadu are better? There are some GDAL bug or weakness?

Answer (score 2):

I used RasterPaletteResolver transformer. It helps.

Comment: Yeah, the problem is that the output format just doesn't support the palettes you have attached to the source. If you don't want the palettes then use the RasterPaletteRemover transformer. Otherwise the RasterPaletteResolver will use the palette to apply the correct color values to the output.